# Visualizing PCA in a scatterplot matrix in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, pca

Im new to R and cleaned the https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices dataset (removed Ocean_proximity column) and used this function on it 
`housing.pca <- prcomp(housing, center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)`
The summary tells me a Proportion of Variance 0.2483 0.2187 0.2014 0.1753 ...
I now want to use a scatterplot matrix to visualize the first 4 PCA Components but i cant figure out how and couldnt find any help

Comment: `plot(housing.pca$rotation)`

Comment: this is not the solution im looking for, i'd like to have a scatterplot matrix that plots the datapoints and not the rotations

Comment: Sorry my mistake, see update as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `plot(as.data.frame(housing.pca$x[,1:4]))` for the first 4 principal components.

Comment: Thanks a lot, even though this was not exactly what i was looking you made me able to find the solution `pairs(housing.pca$x[,1:4])` was what i was looking for

Comment: oh yes - it needs to be a `data.frame` for `plot()` to make the scatterplot matrix. Just fixed my answer accordingly.